# How to stop certain selectors to start function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me start to show my html

```
<div class="row" data-val="SOME_DATA" id="1" data-cur="MORE_DATA">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                    ////more html              
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    ////more html
                </div>
                <div class="media-right">
                    <iframe class="chartjs-hidden-iframe" tabindex="-1" style="display: block; overflow: hidden; border: 0px; margin: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; pointer-events: none; z-index: -1;"></iframe>
                    <canvas id="normalChartGraph" width="170" height="85" style="display: block; width: 170px; height: 85px;"></canvas>
                </div>
                <div class="fill-in-data">
                    ////more html
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My question is if someone pressed on that code. I need to pop-up a modal. That is no problem to that.

This is the JQuery code for it to start the function:

```
$('#show-your-porto-list .row').on('click', showOptions);
```

But my question is I want that an other modal pop-ups when I press on the `.media-right` like you see that is a graph. I want to create a bigger graph in the modal. 
That is my jquery code for it to start the function:

```
$('.col-xs-6 .media-right').on('click',createBiggerChart);
```

But my problem is he also excuted the `showOption()` function because .media-right is the child of `.row`. Is there away to excluded `.media-right` from it.

I don't mean by doing something like this:

```
$('#show-your-porto-list .media-left, #show-your-porto-list .media-body, #show-your-porto-list .fill-in-data').on('click', showOptions);
```

I don't want to do that because at the `.row` I keep certain data that is important to create the modal. Is there a short way to do that without using the long selector line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for this function `$.stopPropagation()`.

Events such as the click event in jQuery traverse the entire XML tree as far as they can for hit elements. The searching can be stopped by calling the `stopPropagation()` function on the event argument that is generated.

Try this:

```
$('.col-xs-6 .media-right').on('click', function(event) { 
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    createBiggerChart() }
);
```

Comment: Is correct but you placed with the wrong function it needed to be this: $('.col-xs-6 .media-right').on('click', function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); createBiggerChart() }); Please correct so I can accept as answer

Comment: thank you very much for helping me and understand what I wanted!